# NSAssert in Singleton : why this code is valid?

Tags: objective-c, singleton, nsassert

i don't understand the use of NSAssert in `+alloc`, as when `+alloc` is called from `+sharedGameManager`, the static `_sharedGameManager` variable is `nil` (so `NSAssert` should stop execution the first time `[self alloc] init]` is called...)

```
+(GameManager*)sharedGameManager {
    @synchronized([GameManager class])                             
    {
        if(!_sharedGameManager)                                    
            [[self alloc] init]; 
        return _sharedGameManager;                                 
    }
    return nil; 
}

+(id)alloc 
{
    @synchronized ([GameManager class])                            
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedGameManager == nil,
                 @"Attempted to allocated a second instance of the Game Manager singleton");
        _sharedGameManager = [super alloc];
        return _sharedGameManager;                                 
    }
    return nil;  
}
```

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of NSAssert the wrong way round?

```
NSAssert( _sharedGameManager==nil, @"Attempted to …");
```

Will throw an Exception if _sharedGameManager **is not** nil. It Asserts that the expression is TRUE, it says "I assert that this must be the case", therefore `_sharedGameManager` must be nil, or an exception is raised. This could only happen if you tried to create 2 instances of this Class.

Comment: oh yes true, i don't why i was sure it was the contrary :) thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a couple of snippets glued together; alloc is an instance method, not a class method (static). If you want to perform initialization of a singleton class, use `+(void)initialize`

The Objective-C runtime claims to guarantee this class method only gets executed once, so it is an effective mechanism for setting up a singleton.  For further reading, hit up Mike Ash's [blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-18-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-iv-odds-and-ends.html) on the topic.

Comment: `+alloc` _is_ a class method. Otherwise, you're right - it does seem Paul just has two unrelated snippets put together. Everyone really needs to use `dispatch_once` to create singletons, and not the pattern given by Apple.

Comment: @wobbals : thanks wobbals, alright thanks for the tips, i found this code in a book, what do you think about this NSAssert? is it a mistake? can it work like that? if so, i would not understand why

Comment: Hmm, it really doesn't look anything like two unrelated snippets. Both methods could only ever work in the presence of each other.

Comment: @hooleyhoop You're right, I wasn't clear in my thinking when I glanced at this code. You _can_ implement the singleton without overriding alloc (as in the Mike Ash example), but there are clearly multiple acceptable approaches.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to guarantee the behavior you want, through Grand Central Dispatch:

```
+ (GameManager *)sharedGameManager {
    static GameManager *sharedGameManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t token;
    dispatch_once(&token, ^{
        sharedGameManager = [[GameManager alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedGameManager;
}
```

`dispatch_once` is guaranteed to be run only once, so your game manager won't be over-initialized. As long as you don't release it, it will stay alive, and it will correctly be released at the end of your program (because of its `static` context).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Oy, you're right. I was reading too quickly, and mixed things up in my head. You're totally right. Whoops.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Anyway, updated my answer to remove that bit.

Comment: @Itai Ferber : thanks for the answer, i'll use this way, i was still wondering why the code used NSAssert, which seems (to me) to block the code, do you have any idea about that?